# How do I control check box selection in menu items, in Java?

Tags: java, checkbox, menu, jframe, menuitem

So, I have a menu set up, and one of the sub menus leads to a choice of three check boxes. When the program first starts, none of them are selected.

```
easy = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Easy");
normal = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Normal");
hard = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Hard");
```

(These have been declared elsewhere.)

I want to be able to control the selection, so that Normal is selected by default. Also, I want to be able to write some code that will ensure that only one box is checked at any one time.

To do this, I just need to know how to select the boxes.

Comment: `so that Normal is "selected" by default.` - Read the API and look for a method with `selected` in the method name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by adding the each button a `ButtonGroup`...

```
ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
bg.add(easy);
bg.add(normal);
bg.add(hard);
```

Then set the default selection...

```
normal.setSelected(true);
```

The button group will ensure that only one option is selected.

Take a look at [How to Use the ButtonGroup Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/buttongroup.html) for more details.

Comment: This, but `normal.setSelected(true)` in your case.

Comment: @Daemon Dam, caught me ;)

Comment: @user2901402 The `ButtonGroup` ensures that only one of the buttons in the group can be selected.  If another button is selected, it will unselect the previous one automatically.  Take a look at the linked tutorial and have a go and see what happens ;)

Comment: @user2901402, did you read the tutorial link? This is why I don't spoon feed answers because then you never bother to follow the links given to you.

Comment: Oh, that is useful. Better than writing a loop for checking whether the items are selected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to control the selection, so that Normal is selected by default.

Read the API and look for a method with `selected` in the method name.